# angular/ionic add attributes conditionally for <ion-tab>

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to add swiping functions conditionally using angularjs,

I have 'customerview' and 'kycview' scope variables in controller.

```
$scope.customerview = 'customerview';
$scope.kycview = 'kycview';
```

I want to remove/hide the '**on-swipe-right**' and '**on-swipe-left**', If the view is 'kycview'

How do write the conditional statement for enable and disable?

### template

```
  <ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-positive">
        <ion-tab id="personalDetails" title="Personal" href="#/newcustomer/PersonalDetails" class="{{persDetailsComplete}}">
            <ion-nav-view name="newcustomer-PersonalDetails"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab id="familyDetails" title="Family &amp; Housing" href="#/newcustomer/FamilyDetails" class="{{familyDetailsComplete}}" disabled="customerState != 'customerview'" on-swipe-right="goBack()" on-swipe-left="goForward()">
            <ion-nav-view name="newcustomer-FamilyDetails"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab id="idproof" title="ID Proof" href="#/newcustomer/Idproof"  class="{{idProofComplete}}" disabled="customerState != 'customerview'">
            <ion-nav-view name="newcustomer-Idproof"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>              
        <ion-tab title="Address" href="#/newcustomer/Address" ng-click="getNewAddress(3);" ng-controller="CustomerController"  class="{{addressComplete}}" disabled="customerState != 'customerview'">
            <ion-nav-view name="newcustomer-Address"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>       
        <ion-tab title="Employment" href="#/newcustomer/EmploymentDetails" class="{{employeementComplete}}" disabled="customerState != 'customerview'">
            <ion-nav-view name="newcustomer-EmploymentDetails"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
        .................
        .................


    </ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ion-tab id="familyDetails" title="Family &amp; Housing" href="#/newcustomer/FamilyDetails" class="{{familyDetailsComplete}}" on-swipe-right="goBack()"  on-swipe-left="goForward()" ng-if="view=='kycview' &&customerview=='kycview'" >

<ion-tab id="familyDetails" title="Family &amp; Housing" href="#/newcustomer/FamilyDetails" class="{{familyDetailsComplete}}" on-swipe-right="goBack()" on-swipe-left="goForward()">
```

Comment: I have 8 tabs for my signup appliation.

Comment: @vishnu Could you please share your tab view?

Comment: @mushin..Is there any other alternative for this problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97605/discussion-between-vishnu-and-muhsin).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming scope variable as

```
$scope.view = "customerview" 
or
$scope.view = "kycview";

ion-tab id="familyDetails" title="Family & Housing" href="#/newcustomer/FamilyDetails" class="{{familyDetailsComplete}}" on-swipe-right="goBack()" on-swipe-left="goForward()" ng-if="view=='customerview'">

ion-tab id="familyDetails" title="Family & Housing" href="#/newcustomer/FamilyDetails" class="{{familyDetailsComplete}}" ng-if="view=='kycview'">
```

Comment: sekhar..I have 8 tabs for my signup appliation.

Comment: Then you can do some thing like this.

ng-if="getView(view)"

Add function as 
$scope.getView = function(view){
if(view == 'kycview'){
return true;
}
return false;
}